# next js only showing compiling /not-found and not rendering app routes

Tags: next.js, error-handling, compilation, http-status-code-404, modulenotfounderror

[browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhmMi.png)Everything was ok in my next js application i turn off my laptop and again when i start my application it showing

> compiling / not-found

everything was ok in my code

Answer (score 0):

try removing `node_modules`, `package-lock.json`, and `.next` folder and re-running `npm i` and then `npm run dev`. These files/folders should re-appear and spin up your app

Comment: Also, is the build version working? npm start?

Comment: Ok let's try....

Comment: I've done all of these still showing not-found

Comment: No npm start not working its giving error

Comment: Is there any way i can fix it?

Comment: I've found that a app directory is existing outside my src folder i dont even know how and when it comes i removed it and finnaly the app is running well

Comment: Ok nice. In nextjs you don't really need the src directory fyi